# how to publish a ASP.NET C# website in a global server

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have developed an asp.net, C# static website.i have completed that project.i have purchased blabla.edu.in domain for that website.Now I want to publish that website to a global server.I don't have any idea about that.Can anyone explain about that?

Comment: Dude, you need a website hosting first. It can be either IIS or a static one.

Comment: also go through your hosting providers documentation. Usually, they will FAQ or articles like GoDaddy does. At the end of the day you just need to upload your compiled project to a directory they provide you with. Well then you might need to do a bit of configuration. But all this info you can get from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you buy the web site name, **the next step is to find a host**, a company that have servers running 24/7 and can rend you space to place your site.

You look for some one that can run asp.net in the version that you have made your site.

Then you rend that space, and you get some ftp password, together with some administration pages  to handle your site parameters, something like this:

[image]

Than using the ftp **you upload your site to the host server** in the directory that the company provide you, and using your administration pages **you set the dns name that you have bought to that host** and what other need to use, like e-mails.